# R Ggplot2: Draw lines between unrelated points

Tags: r, ggplot2, line, geom

I want to draw a line between some unrelated points.

This is my code now:

```
probpostest %>%
  filter(prev==15) %>% 
  mutate(
    stat=replace(stat,stat=="prevalencia","Prevalencia"),
    stat=replace(stat,stat=="probpostestpositivo","Probabilidad\nPostest\nPositivo"),
    stat=replace(stat,stat=="probpostestnegativo","Probabilidad\nPostest\nNegativo"),
    group=replace(group,group=="proven","Confirmada"),
    group=replace(group,group=="proven_likely","Confirmada o\nprobable"),
    group=replace(group,group=="proven_likely_possible","Confirmada,\nprobable o\nposible")) %>% 
  mutate(across(stat, factor, levels=c("Prevalencia","Probabilidad\nPostest\nPositivo","Probabilidad\nPostest\nNegativo")),
         across(c(lower,upper), as.numeric),
         lower=lower/100,
         upper=upper/100) %>%

  ggplot(aes(x=stat,
             y=if_else(is.na(estimator*100),
                       100,
                       estimator*100),
             ymin=lower,ymax=upper,color=stat)) +
  geom_point() + 
  geom_text(aes(label=if_else(is.na(estimator),
                              "NC",
                              paste0(sprintf("%2.2f",estimator*100),"%")),
                vjust=if_else(is.infinite(estimator),
                              1,
                              0.5),
                hjust=-0.25),
            show.legend = FALSE,
            size=4) + # Esta línea quita la "a" de las leyendas
  labs(x=NULL,y=NULL,title = "Figura 5. Probabilidades pre-test y post-test.",
       caption="Prevalencia: probabilidad pre-test.\n\nProbabilidad pos-test positivo y negativo: probabilidad de tener candidiasis invasiva después de obtener un resultado positivo o negativo, respectivamente.\n\nNC: no calculable.")+
  facet_grid(group ~ test,
             scales = "free_y",
             switch = "y"
  ) +
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0),
        legend.position = "none",
        strip.text = element_text(face="bold")) +
  scale_y_continuous(position = "right") +
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

I get this:
[image: Figure1]

and I'd like something like this (done with Paint):
[image]

I tried adding `geom_line(aes(x = stat, group=group)) +` and I could get this, which is not what I need.

[image]

I wonder how I could link the points of my interest and then plot a line between them.
Thank you for your help!

**Reprex:**

```
structure(list(prev = c(15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 
15, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5), group = c("proven", "proven", "proven", "proven_likely", 
"proven_likely", "proven_likely", "proven_likely_possible", "proven_likely_possible", 
"proven_likely_possible", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven_likely", 
"proven_likely", "proven_likely", "proven_likely_possible", "proven_likely_possible", 
"proven_likely_possible", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven_likely", 
"proven_likely", "proven_likely", "proven_likely_possible", "proven_likely_possible", 
"proven_likely_possible", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", 
"proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", 
"proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven", "proven"
), test = c("T2Candida", "T2Candida", "T2Candida", "T2Candida", 
"T2Candida", "T2Candida", "T2Candida", "T2Candida", "T2Candida", 
"Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", 
"Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", 
"T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", 
"T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", 
"T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida", 
"T2Candida", "T2Candida", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", 
"T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", 
"T2Candida", "T2Candida", "T2Candida", "Hemocultivo", "Hemocultivo", 
"Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", "T2Candida + Hemocultivo", 
"T2Candida + Hemocultivo"), stat = c("prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo", "prevalencia", "probpostestpositivo", 
"probpostestnegativo"), estimator = c(0.158, 0.635718612096565, 
0.0361721611721612, 0.404, 0.637998056365403, 0.351610095735422, 
0.561, 0.908822796377835, 0.472165444270771, 0.158, 1, 0.101195559350982, 
0.404, 1, 0.351610095735422, 0.561, 1, 0.534908358936328, 0.158, 
NA, 0.0184192119375146, 0.404, NA, 0.321802457897132, 0.561, 
NA, 0.472165444270771, 0.1, 0.508196721311476, 0.0217391304347826, 
0.1, 1, 0.0625, 0.1, NA, 0.010989010989011, 0.05, 0.328621908127209, 
0.0104166666666667, 0.05, 1, 0.0306122448979592, 0.05, NA, 0.00523560209424084
), lower = c("7.5", NA, NA, "27.6", NA, NA, "42.4", NA, NA, "7.5", 
NA, NA, "27.6", NA, NA, "42.4", NA, NA, "7.5", NA, NA, "27.6", 
NA, NA, "42.4", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), upper = c("27.9", NA, NA, "54.2", 
NA, NA, "69.3", NA, NA, "27.9", NA, NA, "54.2", NA, NA, "69.3", 
NA, NA, "27.9", NA, NA, "54.2", NA, NA, "69.3", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
)), row.names = c(NA, -45L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: You likely want `geom_segment` instead of `geom_line` for individual line segments.

Comment: I tried geom_segment but can't make it work with facet_grid